# Passing a key in a SecByteBlock to an algorithm?

Tags: c++, blowfish, crypto++

I am currently working on a Cryptopp encryption project and would need to pass a key to a Blowfish encryption algorithm.

If I understand correctly I would need to edit these 2 lines:

```
SecByteBlock key(Blowfish::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
prng.GenerateBlock( key, key.size() );
```

My idea would be to pass a string variable (like ekey) here to a SecByteBlock, like so:

```
SecByteBlock key(ekey.data(), ekey.size());
```

But It looks like I'm going the wrong way. 
So, how do I pass a key to the algorithm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The various Crypto++ objects in this area (block/stream ciphers and modes) *do not* take a `SecByteBlock`. They all take a `const byte*` and `size_t`. It comes from [`SymmetricCipher`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_symmetric_cipher.html) interface.

---

> SecByteBlock key(ekey.data(), ekey.size());

Since you have an `ekey` with a `data` and `size`, you should probably use it directly:

```
CBC_Mode< Blowfish >::Encryption enc;
enc.SetKeyWithIV(ekey.data(), ekey.size(), iv.data(), iv.size());
```

***If*** you only have a `SecByteBlock`, then something like:

```
SecByteBlock key(...);
CBC_Mode< Blowfish >::Encryption enc;
enc.SetKeyWithIV(key.data(), key.size(), iv.data(), iv.size());
```

There's a wiki page on Blowfish at [Crypto++ - Blowfish](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Blowfish).

CBC mode in the example above only provides *confidentiality*. You should also consider an [Authenticated Encryption](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Authenticated_Encryption) mode to provide *confidentiality* and *authenticity* assurances.

Comment: I actually use EAX, but it's about the same when it comes to keys. Thanks!

Comment: ***Plus One*** for EAX. I like that mode.